# oracle logon/logoff- Trigger, what privilegs are nessesary?

Tags: oracle, triggers, privileges

I have to protocol some Information concerning logon/logoff to an Oracle database, a short code snipped als follows:
(create table for logs, create Trigger on logon/logoff)

```
CREATE TABLE WHEREVER.LOG_TABLE (
  TIMESTAMP DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  WHAT VARCHAR2(32), 
  TERMINAL VARCHAR2(32)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER WHEREVER.TRIGGER_LOGON AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
DECLARE PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO WHEREVER.LOG_TABLE (
    WHAT,
    TERMINAL
  )
  SELECT
    'LOGON',
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL')
  FROM DUAL
  ;
  COMMIT;
END
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER WHEREVER.TRIGGER_LOGOFF BEFORE LOGOFF ON DATABASE
DECLARE PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO WHEREVER.LOG_TABLE (
    WHAT,
    TERMINAL
  )
  SELECT
    'LOGOFF',
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL')
  FROM DUAL
  ;
  COMMIT;
END
/
```

If I start this script (w/o logon- trigger) as sys as sysdba i get no errors.
But user, who wants to disconnect gets an error

```
ORA 04045: errr during recompilation/revalidation of Trigger
ORA 01031: insufficient privileges
```

I assume, that inserting is not allowed to user.
What could be the minimum Privileg situation, that this table/trigger - combination works, even for users, that are inserted later? who should be owner for table and triggers and in which schema I should put these things (`WHEREVER`)

Comment: Do you also get successful entries in `WHEREVER.LOG_TABLE` when you logon/logoff as SYS? User SYS has `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` privilege which ignores any exception in a database trigger.

Comment: Why `SELECT ... FROM dual`? Simply do `INSERT INTO WHEREVER.LOG_TABLE (WHAT, TERMINAL) VALUES ('LOGOFF', SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL'));`

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit: I can insert the data as every of the tried users, no problem. But the Trigger can't. (I could have written INSERT ... VALUES instead of this, but this should not be the problem. INSERT AS SELECT results from testing, so that I can easy copy and paste to find out, whether selection works.

Comment: Try `GRANT INSERT ON WHEREVER.LOG_TABLE TO CONNECT;` or `GRANT INSERT ON WHEREVER.LOG_TABLE TO PUBLIC`

Comment: tried both, but w/o success :(

Comment: could the pragma cause the Problem?